# R generates NA_real vector in while loop, but not when code line is run separately, how to fix the loop?

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm trying to "pseudo-randomize" a vector in R using a `while` loop.
I have a vector `delays` with the elements that need to be randomized.
I am using `sample` on a vector `values` to index randomly into `delays`. I cannot have more than two same values in a row, so I am trying to use an if else statement. If the condition are met, the value should be added to `random`, and removed from `delays`.

When I run the individual lines outside the loop they are all working, but when I try to run the loop, one of the vector is populated as `NA_real`, and that stops the logical operators from working.
I'm probably not great at explaining this, but can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? :)

```
delay_0 <- rep(0, 12)
delay_6 <- rep(6, 12)

delays <- c(delay_6, delay_0)
value <- c(1:24)


count <- 0
outcasts <- c()
random <- c(1,2)

while (length(random) < 27) {

    count <- count + 1
    b <- sample(value, 1, replace = FALSE)
    a <- delays[b]

    if(a == tail(random,1) & a == head(tail(random,2),1) {
     outcast <- outcasts + 1

    }

    else {
      value <- value[-(b)]
      delays <- delays[-(b)]
      random <- c(random,a)
    }
}
```

Comment: your `b` in loop can be a value bigger than `delays` length. So `a <- delays[b]` becomes `NA`.

Comment: thank you! @cccnrc but even when I shorten "value" the issue seems to remain... When I run the loop, and "value" and "delays" get shorter every time one value is added to "a", when "value is then sampled again, the number that comes out is bigger than the actual length of the vector "value". I'm clearly missing something (probaly pretty obvius), but I just cannot figure out why that happens....

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code:

1. `b` can take a value that is greater than the number of elements in delays. I fixed this by using `sample(1:length(delays), 1, replace = FALSE)`
2. The loop continues when `delays` is empty. You could either  change `length(random) < 27` to `length(random) < 26` I think or add `length(delays) > 0`.

The code:

```
delay_0 <- rep(0, 12)
delay_6 <- rep(6, 12)
delays <- c(delay_6, delay_0)

value <- c(1:24)


count <- 0
outcasts <- c()
random <- c(1, 2)

while (length(random) < 27 & length(delays) > 0) {
  count <- count + 1
  b <- sample(1:length(delays), 1, replace = FALSE)
  a <- delays[b]



  if (a == tail(random, 1) & a == head((tail(random, 2)), 1))
  {
    outcast <- outcasts + 1

  }



  else {
    value <- value[-(b)]
    delays <- delays[-(b)]
    random <- c(random, a)
  }
}
```